# find any of two elements in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In my application when I open page X I expect to see either element A or element B. They are placed in different locations in DOM and can be found using their ids, for example `driver.findElement(By.id("idA"))`

How can I ask webdriver to find either A or B?

There is method `driver.findElements(By)` which will stop waiting when at least one element is found, but this method forces me to use the same locator for A and B.

What is the proper way to reliably find either A or B, so that I don't have to wait implicit timeout?

Comment: I played a bit around with `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id=a] [id=b]"))` but that's not an *or*. I haven't found a css *or* selector.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Element  with id I1 or element  with id I2

xpath: `//E1[@id=I1] | //E2[@id=I2]`

css: `css=E1#I1,E2#I2`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//E1[@id=I1] | //E2[@id=I2]))
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(E1#I1,E2#I2))
```

don't forget about fluentWait mechanism:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return  foo;
};
```

you can get more info about fluentWait [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

IMHO solution to your issue be like:

```
fluentWait(By.xpath(//E1[@id=I1] | //E2[@id=I2]));
fluentWait(By.cssSelector(E1#I1,E2#I2))
```

FYI: [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/) is nice xpath,cssSelector manual

hope this helps you.

Comment: approach using xpath OR operand worked like a charm! First I find any of those elements and then just check `element.getAttribute("id")` to find which one I actually found. Thank you! By the way, do I understand correctly that FluentWait allows to override default implicit timeout set by `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` ?

Comment: What webdriver version are you using ?
With 2.22 `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(E1#I1,E2#I2))` lead to an Exception `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Compound selectors not permitted`

Comment: @VolkerK, I am using 2.24.1 . 
this piece of  code:
driver.get("http://www.tut.by/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String cssAlternativeLink="[id=\"search-7-target\"]>a,[id=\"search-1-target\"]>a";
         List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssAlternativeLink));
        a.get(0).click();
        
worked for me. 
Regards.

Comment: If "xpath: //E1[@id=I1] | //E2[@id=I2]" checks presence of one of the two elements, how would the the syntax look like for checking presence of all elements listed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, which uses a fluent wait as others have suggested. You would need to replace any calls to getDriver() or references to a driver with a driver object or your own method that fetches it.

```
/**
 * Waits for any one of a given set of WebElements to become displayed and
 * enabled.
 * 
 * @param locators
 *            An array of locators to be sought.
 * @param timeout
 *            Timeout in seconds.
 */
protected void waitForOneOfManyToBePresent(By[] locators, int timeout) {
    try {
        (new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeout))
            .until(somethingIsPresent(locators));
    } catch (TimeoutException timeoutEx) {
        // Do what you wish here to handle the TimeoutException, or remove
        // the try/catch and let the TimeoutException fly. I prefer to
        // rethrow a more descriptive Exception
    }
}

/**
 * Condition for presence of at least one of many elements.
 * 
 * @param locators
 *            An array of By locators to be sought.
 * @return Boolean T if at least one element is present, F otherwise.
 */
protected ExpectedCondition<Boolean> somethingIsPresent(By[] locators) {
    final By[] finalLocators = locators;
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (By locator : finalLocators) {
                if (isElementPresent(locator)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return new Boolean(found);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Similar to does element exist, but also verifies that only one such
 * element exists and that it is displayed and enabled.
 * 
 * @param by
 *            By statement locating the element.
 * @return T if one and only one element matching the locator is found, and
 *         if it is displayed and enabled, F otherwise.
 */
protected boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    // Temporarily set the implicit timeout to zero
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // Check to see if there are any elements in the found list
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by);
    boolean isPresent = (elements.size() == 1)
            && elements.get(0).isDisplayed() && elements.get(0).isEnabled();
    // Return to the original implicit timeout value
    driver.manage().timeouts()
                .implicitlyWait(Properties.TIMEOUT_TEST, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Properties.TIMEOUT_TEST is from other personal code, replace with your 
    // own default timeout setting.
    return isPresent;
}
```

My version also checks to make sure that any found element is singular, visible and enabled, but you can remove that easily if you only want to check for existence or if you don't care if your locators are finding multiple matching elements. Checking for the presence of an element by suppressing the default timeout and then calling findElements() may seem clunky, but it's apparently the recommended way to do so in the Selenium API.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an ExpectedCondition for this feel free to use it.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<By> titleIs(final By[] selectors) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<By>() {
        public By apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement el=null;
            for (By selector:selectors) {
                try {
                    el = driver.findElement(selector);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                    // ignore as we are waiting for that to stop
                }
                if (el!=null) return selector; 
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem as well so I made a method for it.
Please note the Method sits inside a class which contains the webdriver as "self._driver". The code is in Python.

An example of calling the Method would be:

self.MES(3, ('name', 'name_of_element1'), ('id', 'id_of_element2'))

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

def MES(self, wait_time, element1, element2):
    '''
    A function to check a website for multiple elements at the same time
    MultiElementSearch. Returns the element if found, or False if neither
    are found.
    It will also throw a ValueError is the element locator type is not
    valid.

    MES(int, (str, str), (str, str)) -> Element or bool
    '''
    time1 = time.time()
    while time.time() < (time1 + wait_time):
        try:
            if element1[0] == 'id':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_id(element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'name':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_name(element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'xpath':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_xpath(element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'link_text':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_link_text(element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'partial_link_text':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(
                    element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'tag_name':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_tag_name(element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'class_name':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_class_name(
                    element1[1])
            elif element1[0] == 'css_selector':
                selection1 = self._driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    element1[1])
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    'The first element locator type is not vaild')
            return selection1

        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            if element2[0] == 'id':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_id(element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'name':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_name(element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'xpath':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_xpath(element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'link_text':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_link_text(element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'partial_link_text':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(
                    element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'tag_name':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_tag_name(element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'class_name':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_class_name(
                    element2[1])
            elif element2[0] == 'css_selector':
                selection2 = self._driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    element2[1])
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    'The second element locator type is not vaild')
            return selection2
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

@pavel_kazlou, well concerning your question on FluentWait: basically there are two types of wait: 
**Explicit wait**

```
WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element)
```

**Implicit wait**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Difference is

- Obvious - Implicit wait time is applied to all elements in your 
  script but Explicit only for particular element
- In Explicit you can configure, how frequently (instead of 500 
  millisecond) you want to check condition.
- In Explicit you can also configure to ignore other exceptions than 
  "NoSuchElement" till timeout.. 
  Use a FluentWait which works similarly to WebDriverWait (which in fact extends FluentWait) but gives you a little more flexibility.

here is WebDriverWait usage example(Use a different WebDriverWait constructor to specify the element polling interval (measured in milliseconds).):

```
new WebDriverWait(webDriver(), 10, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(menuItemXpath)));
```

Using a FluentWait which works similarly to WebDriverWait (which in fact extends FluentWait) but gives you a little more flexibility:in particular the ability to choose the WebDriver exception to ignore.
usage example:

```
new FluentWait(webDriver())
.withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(menuItemXpath)));
```

To conclude my note: fluentWait is an Explicit type of wait and provides you possibility to choose explicitly what type of WebDriver exception to ignore, where as any implicit wait includes fixed amount of time to wait for any webElement. IMHO fluentWait approach is more robust from this point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Java 8` solution.

The wrapper object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SelectorWebElement
{
    private WebElement webElement;
    private By by;

    private SelectorWebElement(WebElement webElement, By by)
    {
        this.webElement = webElement;
        this.by = by;
    }

    public By getBy()
    {
        return by;
    }

    public WebElement getWebElement()
    {
        return webElement;
    }

    private static ExpectedCondition<SelectorWebElement> findFirstElement(By... selectors)
    {
        return driver ->
        {
            for (By selector : selectors)
            {
                try
                {
                    assert driver != null;
                    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(selector);
                    if (webElement.isDisplayed())
                    {
                        return new SelectorWebElement(webElement, selector);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored)
                {

                }
            }

            return null;
        };
    }

    public static SelectorWebElement waitForFirstElement(WebDriver driver,
                                                         long timeout,
                                                         By... selectors)
    {
        Wait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        return (SelectorWebElement) wait.until(findFirstElement(selectors));
    }
}
```

An example code:

```
By badPasswordSelector = By.cssSelector("...");
By myAccountPage = By.cssSelector("...");
SelectorWebElement selectorWebElement = SelectorWebElement.waitForFirstElement(driver, 5, badPasswordSelector, myAccountPage);

By matchedSelector = selectorWebElement.getBy();

if (matchedSelector.equals(badPasswordSelector))
{
    System.out.println("Bad password");
} else if (matchedSelector.equals(myAccountPage))
{
    System.out.println("Successfully logged in");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR ANYONE LOOKING TO DO THIS IN PYTHON**

Here's a very straightforward method that works for me, first I use the `implicitly_wait` method so the driver automatically waits the given ammount of time until it can find the element:

`driver.implicitly_wait(30) #driver constantly tests for 30 seconds before complaining`

Now if I want to find either one of two different elements (or the same element in different ways) I just do the following:

```
#We see if either is present, we only need one for the if statement to be true
if driver.find_element_by_class_name('dir') or driver.find_element_by_class_name('dirSel'):

    #Set wait time to 0 so we can try both fast (since we know one was found but not which)
    driver.implicitly_wait(0) 

    try:
        ele = driver.find_element_by_class_name('dir')
    except: 
        ele = driver.find_element_by_class_name('dirSel')

    driver.implicitly_wait(30) #reset the driver's wait time.
```

This can easily be turned into a function and scaled to search for more than two elements, just wanted to avoid that since the original post asked for help in Java. Nevertheless the selenium commands are pretty uniform across languages so I help this can help those of you not working in python as well :)