# How to quickly check if one of two elements exists selenium?

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have two elements I am searching for using this function:

```
 Private Function IsElementPresent(by As By, driver As ChromeDriver) As Boolean
    Try
        driver.FindElement(by)
        Return True
    Catch generatedExceptionName As NoSuchElementException
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Here is the basics of my code:

```
If IsElementPresent(By.Name("Email"), driver) Then
     'user is not logged in already do stuff
ElseIf IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Search for new keywords using a phrase, website or category')]"), driver) Then
     'user has already logged in do other stuff
end if
```

Now this works alright. The problem is it seems as if the first check is blocking the second from firing even when the element is visible. It seems as if it is waiting for the first if statement to return false before it will check the second if statement. With my implicit wait timeout at 10 seconds this adds a lot of extra time for a simple check. Is there any way to perform these checks without the blocking? Sorry if it's a dumb question just scratching my head a bit.

Comment: What do you mean blocking?? Actually your question is not clear to me, could you explain little bit more clear??

Comment: I am probably using the wrong terminology my apologies. I just mean if my second if statment is true and that the element exists than the first if statement hangs up the program for the duration of the implicit wait time as it takes an exception being thrown to return false and continue on.

Comment: So why are using try catch here?? You can just simplify it using findElements instead..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find any of two elements in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018530/find-any-of-two-elements-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, don't use `Try..Catch` here. You can just simplify it to check element existence by using `FindElements` instead as below :-

```
Private Function IsElementPresent(by As By, driver As ChromeDriver) As Boolean
      Return driver.FindElements(by).Count > 0         
End Function
```

Comment: This still unfortunately waits for the full implicit wait time of the first even if the second is present. What I need is for it to search for both elements at the same time and if one element is found than cancel the search for the other one and assume that it's not going to be there.

Comment: Actually implicit wait waits for given time if element not found, it's the functionality of implicit wait, you if you don't want to wait don't use implicit wait then..:)

Comment: And if you want to find element both at the same time you need to use `|` with `By.xpath("first element xpath | second element xpath")` and then determine element by their tag name ...:)